# RaiBlocks blockchain (Nano) local client (rai_node –daemon) cannot open new account

Tags: blockchain

I run a raiblocks blockchain node on Linux:
./rai_node --daemon

I created an account and from NANEX made a transfer to that account of some NANO coins.
I checked in the explorer
https://www.nanode.co
and it shows the payment and the HASH, and shows it as un-pocketed yet.

To complete the opening of the new account, I followed the steps of the manual below, but it fails:
https://www.nanode.co/docs#rpc-guide-connecting

**In step 1 of the above manual:
The RPC command “accounts_pending” returns an empty string and not the HASH that appears in the Explorer above.**
For the RPC command I used both “curl” and the nodejs library “axios” that writes in the online manual.

With “curl”:

curl -g -d
‘{“action”: “accounts_pending”,“accounts”: [“xrb_acountnumber”],“count”: 1}’
‘[::ffff:127.0.0.1]:7076’

With nodejs:

// Step 1. Retrieve hash of the send block that you sent from your wallet

const pending = await rpc.post(’/’, {
action: ‘accounts_pending’,
accounts: [“xrb_acountnumber”]
})

The above are not working even after I manually downloaded the Nano_blockchain into my local client and it is almost synchronized.

**Also in the step no 4:**

// Step 4. Publish your open block to the network using "process"

const processResult = await rpc.post(’/’, {
action: ‘process’,
block: newBlock.data.block
})
console.log(processResult.data.hash) // The hash of your newly published open block

**it returns the error:**

**data: { error: ‘Gap source block’ } }**

**instead of the hash of your newly published open block**

Any help would very much appreciated